# Como fazer para o botão voltar feche a activity sem voltar para a anterior(termine a app)?

Tags: android, android-activity

A activity login está como MAIN e serve para fazer login no fireBase.
Se o utilizador já estiver logado vai direto para a activity do menu principal.

Queria que, na activity do menu principal, quando o usuário clicasse no botão voltar não voltasse para a activity login e sim que a aplicação terminasse.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ruim, e tem vários exemplo por ai, é melhor fazer uma pesquisa antes de perguntar.

Comment: Tambem posso te sugerir trocar a logica, assim,  Atividade abertura(SplashScreen)-> Checklogin (verifica se está logado se sim)-> Menu Principal, se não-> Login atividade , e uma leitura sobre ciclo de vida das atividades.

Answer (score 2):

Na Activity login, logo após a linha que tem `startActivity()` coloque `finish();`. Isso irá fechar a Activity login fazendo que ao clicar no voltar não volte a ela e a aplicação seja fechada.

Qualquer coisa assim:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

O mesmo pode ser conseguido recorrendo a *intent flags*:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

No entanto, como só tem uma Activity no Stack, é melhor usar o primeiro método.

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou limpar a back stack das Activities?

Lá no intent que tu faz **a transição da tela de login para a outra tela**, adicione a flag: **intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);**

Espero que dê certo!

Comment: A flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) não faz isso.

Comment: Tem como colocar o trecho do seu código?